# Issues with building matplotlib-cpp

Tags: cmake

I downloaded the [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp)
And I created a CMakeList.txt to build it. Contents of CmakeList.txt

```
project(myproject)
find_package(Python2 COMPONENTS Development NumPy)
target_include_directories(myproject PRIVATE ${Python2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Python2_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(myproject Python2::Python Python2::NumPy)
```

But as soon as I hit command `cmake ../` I get this error

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python2: /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found version "2.7.17") found components: Development NumPy Interpreter 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "myproject" which is not
  built by this project.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "myproject" which is not built by
  this project.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/heisenbug/myproject/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Can I get some help regarding this issue, I think the issue lies in the name `myproject`

Comment: IMHO this would be better asked on [so] - I *think* you need an `add_library()` or `add_executable()` to define an actual target before you call the target_include_directories or target_link_libraries

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: The original `Makefile` is perfect. Run `make` and the 12 examples are created in `matplotlib-cpp/examples/build/`. .... The included `contrib/CMakeList.txt` seems to trash the original Makefile.

Comment: Simply running `make` did the thing. Thanks for your help. I am new with cmake so was stuck here!!!